# cant get the tag of a post displayed django

Tags: python, django

I've built a blog kinda app and there is a location section. I can add a location for a post when I create it (with django taggit) and when I search for it let's say Paris http://127.0.0.1:8000/tag/paris/ it shows me all the posts that have that tag.

the thing i couldn't add is that on my homepage right next to the username I want to show the location that post has and when I click it I want to see the other posts that have that tag, so if post1 has the tag of Paris i'll click on it and it'll show me http://127.0.0.1:8000/tag/paris/

I've tried this just to show the tag the post has

```
location:<strong> {{post.tags}} </strong></a>-->
```

but it says location: blog.Post.None

btw http://127.0.0.1:8000/tag/paris/ and all other tags work. I can see all the posts that have that tag when I search this in the search bar. I just can't seem to put the link to it anywhere.

i'll try to put just the relevant parts of the code.
home.html

```
{% for post in posts %}
             
              <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>

              location:<strong> {{post.tags}} </strong></a>-->

{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
class TagIndexView(ListView):
    model = Post
    paginate_by = '10'
    context_object_name = "posts"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(tags__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug')).order_by('-date_posted')
```

urls.py

```
path('', PostListView.as_view(), name="blog-home"), 
path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name="user-posts"),
path('tag/<slug:slug>/', TagIndexView.as_view(), name='tagged'),
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through and create a link for each tag like below.

```
{% for post in posts %}
             
              <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>

              {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
                    location:<strong> <a href="{% url 'tagged' tag.slug %}">{{ tag.name }}</a> </strong></a>-->

              {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```